# How to get the fully qualified class name without instantiating the class first?

Tags: java, class

I want to get the class name from within a static method but without instantiating the class.

The following code snippet is not what I want to achieve because it instantiated the class first.

```
package a.b.c;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new Program().getClass().getName());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried :

```
System.out.println(Program.class.getName());
```